# PHP design pattern for conditional instantiation of classes

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm looking for best practices in the following scenario (using Laravel, but that's not relevant): I have a method `strokePet`,  which depending on the request payload, will instantiate a `DogStroker` or a `CatStroker` class. The `strokePet` method is called via an API endpoint.

```
class PetController
{
    public function strokePet($request)
    {
        if ($request->pet == 'dog') {
            $stroker = new DogStroker;
        else if ($request->pet == 'cat') {
            $stroker = new CatStroker;
        } 
        $stroker->stroke();
    }
}

class DogStroker
{
    public function stroke()
    {
        echo 'grr';
    }
}

class CatStroker
{
    public function stroke()
    {
        echo 'prr';
    }
}
```

Is there any advantage in creating a `PetStroker` interface, e.g.

```
interface PetStroker
{
    public function stroke();
}
```

or is there some design pattern I'm missing here which would make this more OOP-idiomatic? (I'm aware this may get flagged for being too vague.)

Comment: Having an interface (or parent class, which could even be abstract) helps keep your code clean once you start adding features (since you can do things like $x instanceof PetStroker). As for design patterns: I'd suggest implementing this in a factory pattern, eg. create the mentioned abstract class PetStroker and give it a static method `PetStroker::Create($pet)` which either returns a CatStroker or DogStroker or whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It allows to encapsulate object selection for the provided input, and return something that only implements a given interface.

In your case, factory method can look something like:

```
public static function GetStroker($request) // or Create($pet), as suggested in comments
{
    if ($request->pet == 'dog') { return new DogStroker; }
    if ($request->pet == 'cat') { return new CatStroker; } 
    return new DefaultStroker; // or throw exception
}
```

You then can use it to retrieve a correct implementation, hiding selection logic from the caller.